# Wifi problem with one particular SSID

Tags: wireless, 15.10, atheros, ath9k

I have a Wifi problem with only **one** SSID. My internet works with any SSID except one.

I used wireless-info script to generate reports:

- [Connection okay](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16460668/)
- [Connection not okay](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16460679/)

How can I fix the connection with this SSID?

Comment: Please (a) give this question a proper meaningful title, and (b) include as much detail as reasonably fits in the question itself. I have _no idea_ what problem you're experiencing with what. You can always [edit] this question to improve it.

Comment: Sorry @TRiG, this is my first ask. I need to improve my question ?  Thank's.

Comment: Please do not put `SOLVED` in the title, just check the checkmark onto the answer which was most helpful for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a crowded frequency (2.462) Use a less crowded frequency to fix the issue.

You have

```
3   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
3   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Try channel 6 instead.

You need to change your router settings to broadcast on channel 6 instead of the current channel 11.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Without changing channel the other devices are connected except my laptop. I try to update my distibution to ubuntu 16.04...

Comment: @fcafra Your other devices may have different firmware if not linux devices and so may have aspects such as interference-mitigation which may not be available in the current linux driver or module for that device. It would be a heck of a lot easier to just change the channel as being on the same channel also causes problems for your neighbors as well on that same frequency. Channel 11 is also a higher frequency which makes it more susceptible to solid object interference. Lower frequencies more easily pass through solid objects.

Comment: thank's....  i change the router setting and i try channel 6. Thnk's !!!!!!  Now Working....